# AJAX Request Not Completing After Adding Express Middleware

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a snippet of code that sends a `DELETE` request via Jquery that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.formula-block').on('click', function(e){
if (e.target.className == 'button-warning pure-button') {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/formula-list/' + this.id,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: reload
  });
 }
});

function reload () {
  window.location.reload(true);
  }
});
```

This worked fine until I updated a piece of middleware in my application.

I was using the following snippet to make MongoDB available to my program in my `app.js` file:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas', (e, db) => {
    if (e) return next(e);
    req.db = db;
    next();
 });
});
```

However, I recently added the following line of code before the last pair of brackets

```
req.on('end', () => { req.db.close(); });
```

and now the `SUCCESS` portion of my `AJAX` request no longer works.

I assume this is because the AJAX request is waiting for a response and not getting it because the last line is clipping it, so `success` is never called.

My main issue is that I want the page to refresh with the updated list of items after something gets deleted.  I'm agnostic how this happens, but for now my arrangement no longer works.

If it helps, here's the server side code that received the `DELETE` request:

```
router.delete('/formula-list/:id', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db.collection('users');
  var f_id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
  db.updateOne({"_id": new ObjectID(req.user.id)}, { $pull: {
    "formulas": {"f_id": f_id}
  }}, function(err, r){
      if(err) {throw err;}
      assert.equal(null, err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and see whether you are getting any response back from your ajax call and, if so, what that response is.  You first need to know what is getting back to the client or whether the issue is that no response is being sent.

Comment: Are you calling `res.send`? Btw, you should check if db is defined in your req before trying to close the connection or listen to req end event in the connect callback.

Comment: I do not see anywhere where you are actually sending a response to the request.  The browser will not know the request has finished until you do `res.send(...)` on the server.  So, when your DB operation is done, you should `res.send()` something back to the client so it knows the request is done.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to solve your problem, but maybe you can gain some insight by adding an `error` handler to your AJAX call:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: '/formula-list/' + this.id,
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: reload,
    error: function() {
        console.log(arguments);
    }
  });
```

If the AJAX success handler worked before, and doesn't anymore, it's likely an error is happening. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but when I run this no errors are turning up.

Comment: Try some debugging.
1. Make sure the AJAX call is sent.
2. Add print statements in the back end
Hope you figure it out!

Comment: The request is hitting. If I manually refresh the page everything is updated.  And like I said it worked fine before I added the `req.on('close')....` verbiage that got me into trouble right here.

Comment: Then it sounds like something in your Express.js script is blocking.  The request is never sent back to the front end.  Maybe the Express docs can help here?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like `complete: function(){reload}`, so ajax will reload once it finished the delete function.

(Side note: I have ran into this type of problem before and it only worked on certain browsers because others doesn't support the `delete` method)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments on my question, the issue was that I was not explicitly creating any sort of response with my request, which was the problem.

All I had to do was add `res.end()` to my express snippet and the issue was solved.

This did the trick:

```
router.delete('/formula-list/:id', function(req, res){
  var db = req.db.collection('users');
  var f_id = new ObjectID(req.params.id);
  db.updateOne({"_id": new ObjectID(req.user.id)}, { $pull: {
    "formulas": {"f_id": f_id}
  }}, function(err, r){
             assert.equal(null, err);
             assert.equal(1, r.modifiedCount);
           });
  res.end();
});
```